# MVC Razor Ajax.BeginForm Update element during OnSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my MVC search form, I have a date field with "-" and "+" buttons to move to the previous and next day, executing the search each time.

My issue is that when the -/+ button is pressed, it will pass the current form to the controller, including the date in the date box, the controller then does as its told and subtracts/adds the day as appropriate and executes the search.

However, when the Ajax request is complete, the original date is still in the text box so that when -/+ is pressed again, its still works of the original date.

What I need to do is to update the text box with the date that has been updated by the controller but I am not sure how to.

I've looked at the "OnSuccess" event, but I cannot seem to pass the response from the Ajax call to it to then use jQuery to update the Search section.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "results", OnBegin = "$('#btnSubmit').button('loading');", OnSuccess = "FormLoaded()" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="<" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnPrev" style="width: 30px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px" name="ScrollButton" />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @style = "width: 100px; display: inline" } })
    <input type="submit" value=">" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnNext" style="width: 30px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px" name="ScrollButton" />    

    <div id="results">

    ... Results appear here when search is executed ...

    </div>
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    function FormLoaded(ajaxResponse) {
        $('#btnSubmit').button('reset');

        // ...Do something else with the ajaxResponse....

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "results", OnBegin = "$('#btnSubmit').button('loading');", OnSuccess = "FormLoaded" }))
```

{
   }

remove () from OnSuccess.

Comment: Well, that does something, but not quite ... The ajaxResponse appears to be an html fragment, not an instance of the model.

Comment: Do you want to get data from controller action and update? Can you paste your controller code here?

Comment: Ahhhh... you have a point there.... It's returning a PartialView... not a model...

Comment: Obviously. That's the response from the call.

Comment: Indeed.... So will need to return the Model and then use the "OnSuccess" to update the DIV with the Partial View

Comment: You can also return json response with model and your partial view as string. Then in onSuccess, parse json and use them however you want.